# Why is zsh not able to read ~ (tilde) from a path in a script?

Tags: shell, path, export, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When `zsh` was exporting a `PATH` from a script, it didn't read the path correctly.

My `PATH` was `export PATH="~/path/to/stuff/"`, but when I tried to run a command located at that path, `zsh` could not find it.

When I changed the `PATH` to `export PATH="$HOME/path/to/stuff/"`, then the `zsh` was able to run the command.

**EDIT:** The strange thing is that I just checked this and it's working again with `export PATH="~/path/to/stuff/"`. There must be something weird going on with my dev environment.

**EDIT 2:** I failed to mention earlier that the script I am reading `export PATH="~/path/to/stuff/"` from is building a local dev environment for a team of developers who mainly use `bash` as their shell. I prefer to use `zsh` so I have to get my shell to play nice with all of the configs for the dominant `bash` setup across the team.

Comment: Only *unquoted* tildes are subject to tilde expansion. At the very least, use `export PATH=~"/path/to/stuff"`.

Comment: As chepner said. Try `export PATH=~/"path/to/stuff/"` or `export PATH="$HOME/path/to/stuff/"` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following code to get what you want:

```
export PATH=~/Desktop/Capture/
echo $PATH

# Result:    /Users/swift/Desktop/Capture/
```

Although, when you're using a string, you'll get this:

```
export PATH="~/Desktop/Capture/"
echo $PATH                      

# Result:    ~/Desktop/Capture/
```

> **So to get it right, you'll have to try this approach**:

```
tilde=~
export PATH="${tilde}/Desktop/Capture/"
echo $PATH                             

# Result:    /Users/swift/Desktop/Capture/
```

*P.S. Also, there's one useful command for tilde to be expanded*.

*Here's an example*:

```
echo tilda=~

# Result:    tilda=~
```

*Use `magicequalsubst` command in `zsh`*:

```
set -o magicequalsubst
echo tilda=~    

# Result:    tilda=/Users/swift
```

Comment: That's interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Does this work the same with both `zsh` and `bash`? I edited my answer with **Edit 2:** which explains why it has to work with `bash` and `zsh`.

Comment: It works fine for both: `bash` and `zsh`. But `magicequalsubst` command is for zsh.